# How to create a random array with a specific range

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a random array with 6 elements from (0-300)
and the distance between the number and the next one is 20 , i mean ( 0,20,40,60,...,300)

here is my code to create 6 random  array , but not in specific difference

in JS

```
var myNumArray = randomArray(6,0,300);
function random_number(min,max) {

return (Math.round(((max-min)) * Math.random() + min));
 }

function randomArray(num_elements,min,max) {

var nums = new Array;

for (var element=0; element<num_elements; element++) {
    nums[element] = random_number(min,max);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? If they're random how can they be with a given distance?

Comment: you are passing 3 parameters to "randomArray" but declaring 2, what does it mean 6 elements from 0-300 with jumps of 20? nothing here is random...

Comment: no , i try it , i got a 6 numbers randomly has a range from 0 -300

Comment: Like others have said there is nothing random about selecting two numbers between 0 and 300 that are 20 apart. You'll have to be more clear.

Comment: @Itay  look , i want the numbers that are in a range from 0-300 , has a distance between the number and the next number 20

Comment: Still unclear. You can perhaps give us a few examples of the output you're expecting.

Comment: i have a range from(0) to (300) , and i want 6 numbers ,  `randomArry(6,0,300)` i mean that 6 numbers , and a range from 0-300

Comment: i am not good in english :(

Comment: the output will be randomly ... [ 40,80,300,20,100,20]

Comment: [ 40,80,300,20,100,20]  - they are not 20 apart. Divisible by 20 is what you mean? *Does it have to end with 300?*

Comment: @OraibAboRob, so what you're saying is that you'd like to *shuffle* a pre existing array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since --i assume from your example-- the distance is fixed to 20, you could just use 15 as limit (instead of 300), then multiply random_number by 20 at the end.

Here how your code should like : ([working exemple here](http://js.do/code/71477) )

```
var myNumArray = randomArray(6,0,15);

function random_number(min,max) {
    return (Math.round(((max-min)) * Math.random() + min));
}

function randomArray(num_elements,min,max) {

    var nums = new Array;
    for (var element=0; element<num_elements; element++) {
        nums[element] = random_number(min,max)*20;
    }
}
```

This give the wanted result. You can also adjust it to make the distance not hard coded :

```
// distance variable declaration;
// ...
nums[element] = random_number(min,max)*distance;
```

Comment: you're welcome. wrote it on the fly, i hope it respond to your need.

Comment: @OraibAboRob did you change the 1st line to var `myNumArray = randomArray(6,0,15);` i tested and it work fine.

Comment: It worrrks :) thank you , i didn't call the function with correct way , thaaank youu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93189/discussion-between-inaliahgle-and-oraib-abo-rob).